# DataTables search not working and checkbox for each row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

Hi I'm working with Datatable. I am populating it using PHP Codeigniter and AJAX request. The data is loading fine but the search function of dataTable is not working.

Here's the ajax call so far

```
function get_card_info(id){
        if(id != ''){
            $.ajax({
                'url' : '<?php  echo base_url('getter/get_card_info/'); ?>'+id,
                'type' : 'POST', 
                'data' : {'id' : id},
                'cache' : false,
                'success' : function(data){ 
                    if ($.trim(data)){  
                        var json = JSON.parse(data);
                        var suffix = json.info[0].Citizen_Suffix !== null ? json.info[0].Citizen_Suffix : '';
                        var currentBarangay = json.currentAddress[0].Barangay_Name != 'Others' ? ', '+json.currentAddress[0].Barangay_Name : '';
                        $('#card_number').text(json.info[0].card_id);
                        $('#fullname').text(json.info[0].Citizen_Title+' '+json.info[0].Citizen_LastName+', '+json.info[0].Citizen_FirstName+' '+json.info[0].Citizen_MiddleName+' '+suffix);
                        $('#address').text(json.currentAddress[0].Address_Name+currentBarangay);

                    //Image
                    var url = '<?php echo base_url('resources/images/citizen_photo/'); ?>'+id+'.jpeg';
                    $('#photo').attr('src', url);

                    $('#dt-services').DataTable( {
                        "ajax": '<?php echo base_url('getter/get_merchant_services/'); ?>'+id,
                        "destroy": true,
                        "paging": false,
                        "columnDefs": [{
                         'targets': 0,
                         'className': 'dt-body-center',
                         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                             return '<input type="checkbox" '+(data == 'true' ? 'checked' : '')+'>' ;
                         }
                        }],
                        "columns" :[
                            {data: ""},
                            {data: "card_id"},
                            {data: "Citizen_FirstName"}
                        ]

                    } );
                }
                else{   
                    ShowAlert('Error', 'Card Not Found', 'danger');
                }


            },
            'error': function(request, error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        }
        else{
            ShowAlert('Error', 'Please enter card number', 'warning');
        }
    };
```

Also, i'm trying to put checkbox so I can get the selected values. Any guide on this? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what `search function of dataTable` is because it's never supplied. And please go into more detail of why it's not working such as your expected output; actual output and please post any attempts of trying to debug this (with the info that you found)

Comment: @WillParky93 I think he made it clear that he wants the search to work. Search is enabled by default in datatables. It's best if you post the console logs

Comment: A quick google search about "DataTables Checkbox" gave me this: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

Comment: Search is enabled by default, yes. But when I tried typing in the search bar, nothing is happening and there is no error in the console log.

Comment: @hungrykoala I tried adding the columnDefs and Select but the checkbox is not showing

Comment: Not particular related, but what is the meaning with `$('<div/>').text(data).html()` as a checkbox value attribute?

Comment: no error in console is one thing but does it actually send the request ? you should see this in the "network" tab... (google dev tools)

Comment: Since you have `serverSide`  and `processing` set to true, the search is looking for server side code to process it, can you post your sever side code?

Comment: I removed the serverSide and processing and it works. Now my problem is adding checkbox to each row and get selected values. @davidkonrad I saw some guide somewhere and the checkbox actually shows, but is there a way that you know how to do it? sorry, newbie here.

Comment: @Alvinrightback, add `checked` to the returned string, for example if `data` is `true` or `false` `return '<input type="checkbox" '+(data == 'true' ? 'checked' : '')+'>' ` this will set the checkboxs initial state according to `data`...

Comment: @davidkonrad I removed the columnDefs since i'm not really sure if that's the right way to add checkbox and I can get the selected values.

Comment: @davidkonrad where should I put that return?

Comment: It is the right way, you should add the return in the section you just deleted. This adds checkboxes with an initial state to the column. There are many answers how to get the values from checkboxes within a DataTable here on SO.

Comment: @davidkonrad ok so i've added back the columnDefs and changed the return. For the 'columns' is it correct to add the {data: ""} or this is where I should put the value of the checkbox?

Comment: `data: ""` if you not want to bind it to a particular attribute in the JSON, but then `data` always will be `null` in the `render` callback.

Comment: @davidkonrad so if that is the case, i mean, i need to get the values of the selected checkbox. should I put the ID in there instead of ""?